# Using FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING with Datatables Editor

Tags: php, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I want to trim the results from 2 tables and match them.  I am currently using this in a PDO script and works fine.  I am trying to convert all my tables to Datatables Editor but am running into this issue.

```
->leftJoin( 'FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING(disc_rq_activations.Related_SN,1, 13), SUBSTRING(disc_Activations.Device_ID, 1,13))' )
```

The above throws no errors but fails to load results.

here is my regular php script

```
FROM disc_rq_activations RQ
LEFT JOIN
   disc_Activations VZ
   ON FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING(RQ.Related_SN,1, 13), SUBSTRING(VZ.Device_ID, 1,13))
   #ON IF(length(Related_SN) = 15,FIND_IN_SET(LEFT(Related_SN, length(Related_SN) - 1), VZ.Device_ID),Related_SN)
WHERE
   VZ.Device_ID IS NULL
   AND RQ.District = "'.$region.'"
   AND STR_TO_DATE(RQ.Sold_On, "%b %e, %Y %l:%i %p")  BETWEEN "'.$mindate.'" AND "'.$maxdate.'"
   AND RQ.Product_Name != "ISPU Activation"
   AND RQ.Product_Name != "ISPU New Act"
   GROUP BY RQ.Tracking_, RQ.Related_SN
```

The above works just fine.

How can I implement this in datatables?

Full datatables script

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;



require '../../../vendor/autoload.php';
include( "lib/DataTables.php" );

use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field,
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
    DataTables\Editor\Options,
    DataTables\Editor\Upload,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate,
    DataTables\Editor\ValidateOptions;

    Editor::inst( $db, 'disc_rq_activations' )
        ->fields(
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.ID' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Invoice_' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Tracking_' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Qty' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Product_SKU' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Product_Name' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Unit_Rebate' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Related_Product' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Related_SKU' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Related_SN' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Related_Cost' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Related_Price' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Rate_Plan' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Customer' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Sales_Person' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Sales_Person_ID' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Sold_On' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Invoiced_At' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Original_Invoice' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Original_Sales_Date' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Contract_' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.SOC_Code' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.SOC_Code_2' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Extra_Field' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Port_Number' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Region' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.District' ),
                Field::inst( 'disc_rq_activations.Vendor_Account_Name' ),
                Field::inst( 'daily_notes.note' ),
                Field::inst( 'daily_notes.note_id' ),



        )

// Need to convert this as it is showing all as null because one column is 18 digits and the other is 16 digits for the most part.  Some IDs are 13 digits. 
    ->leftJoin( 'disc_Activations', 'disc_rq_activations.Related_SN', '=', 'disc_Activations.Device_ID' )
    ->leftJoin( 'daily_notes', 'daily_notes.note_id', '=', 'disc_rq_activations.ID' )
    ->where('disc_Activations.Device_ID', null)


    ->debug( true )
        ->process( $_POST )
        ->json();
```